# How to prevent diagrams from getting squeezed

Tags: diagrams

I am trying to create the following diagram but the issue is that the proportions seem to be off. Like it looks squeezed vertically.

[image]

My code is as follows

```
\begin{tikzcd}
  &  & Z \arrow[rrdd, "g"] \arrow[lldd, "f"'] \arrow[dd, "\exists! h", dotted] &  &   \\
  &  &                                                                         &  &   \\
X &  & X \times Y \arrow[rr, "\pi_{Y}"'] \arrow[ll, "\pi_{X}"]                 &  & Y
\end{tikzcd}
```

Is there a way to make it look more symmtric?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use empty rows and columns for spacing. Just set `row sep` and `column sep` at the beginning of the `tikzcd`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.5cm, column sep=1cm]
  & Z \arrow[rd, "g"] \arrow[ld, "f"'] \arrow[d, "\exists! h", dotted] \\
X & X \times Y \arrow[r, "\pi_{Y}"'] \arrow[l, "\pi_{X}"] & Y
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```